# Xamarin osmdroid binding gives an error: 'BingMapTileSource' does not implement interface member

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, osmdroid, aar

Xamarin osmdroid binding gave me an error

> 'BingMapTileSource' does not implement interface member
>   'IStyledTileSource.Style'. 'BingMapTileSource.Style' cannot implement
>   'IStyledTileSource.Style' because it does not have the matching return
>   type of 'Object'

I tried to put

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.bing']/class[@name='BingMapTileSource']/method[@name='getStyle' and count(parameter)=0]" name="managedReturn">java.lang.Object</attr>
```

to Transforms\Metadata.xml but it didn't help.
If anyone knows how to fix it, please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try Java.Lang.Object? That did it for me.